# Ordering no of strings according to given order

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, connection-string, mergesort

If the OrderString is ”dcfbae”, it means d > c > f > b > a > e, unlike the lexicographic(dictionary)
ordering where we have a > b > c > d > e > f.
all are lower case alphabets.

I'm getting SEG FAULT..i know its somewhat related to pointers but i'm unable to figure it out..
here's my code :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<string.h>
#define MAX 1001
int min(int x,int y){
    return (x>y)?y:x;
}
int check(char a,char b,char *order){
    int i,x,y;
    for(i=0;i<strlen(order);i++){
        if(a==order[i])
            x=i;
        if(b==order[i])
            y=i;
    }
if(x>y)
    return 1;
else
    return 0;
}
int compare(char *a,char *b,char *order){
   int i=0,l1=strlen(a),l2=strlen(b);
   for(i=0;i<min(l1,l2);i++){
       if(a[i]==b[i])
          continue;
       else{
           if(check(a[i],b[i],order)==1)
              return 1;
           else
              return 0;
       }
   }
}
void merge(int l,int r,int mid,char **string,char *order){
    int size1=mid-l+1;
    int size2=r-mid;
    char a[size1][MAX],b[size2][MAX];
    int i,j,k;
    for(i=0;i<size1;i++)
       strcpy(a[i],string[l+i]);
    for(i=0;i<size2;i++)
       strcpy(b[i],string[mid+1+i]);
    i=0;
    j=0;
    k=0;
    while(i<size1 && j<size2){
       if(compare(a[i],b[j],order)==0){
          strcpy(string[k],a[i]);
          i++;
       }
       else{
          strcpy(string[k],b[j]);
          j++;
       }
    k++;
   }
   while(i<size1){
      strcpy(string[k],a[i]);
      i++;
      k++;
   }
   while(j<size2){
      strcpy(string[k],b[j]);
      j++;
      k++;
   }
 }
 void mergesort(int l,int r,char **string,char *order){
      int mid=(l+r)/2;
      if(l<r){
         mergesort(l,mid,string,order);
         mergesort(mid+1,r,string,order);
         merge(l,r,mid,string,order);
      }
    return ;
 }
int main(){
    char order[MAX];
    scanf("%s",order);
    int T;
    scanf("%d",&T);
    char string[T][MAX];
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<T;i++)
        scanf("%s",string[i]);
    mergesort(0,T-1,string,order);
    for(i=0;i<T;i++)
      printf("%s\n",string[i]);
   return 0; 
  }
```

i'm using mergesort algorithm..
thanks in advance :)

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger to see where it faults?

Comment: Alternatively, have you tried running it under a memory-checking tool such as valgrind?  That might give you additional information about the nature and ultimate cause of the error.

Comment: Note that `char [][]` and `char **` aren't the same thing. I'm betting you're getting compiler warnings that you are ignoring.

Comment: You implement no protection against overrunning the bounds of your order string or of the strings in your sort set on input.

Comment: Start at the top x and y are used not initialized.

Comment: To correct the type-matching problem in function `mergesort()`, declare the third argument as `char string[][MAX]` or as `char (*string)[MAX]`.

Comment: *unlike the lexicographic(dictionary) ordering where we have a > b > c > d > e > f. *  This is not the dictionary ordering,  and 'a' is 65, 'b'  is 66, etc.  so 'a' is NOT greater than 'b', etc

Comment: The posted code does not compile.  Always compile with all warnings enabled.  (with gcc, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`) Then fix the resulting list of problems.

Comment: if orderstring is asdfgh then a has the first priority then s then d and so on..

Comment: this loop: `for(i=0;i<T;i++)
        scanf("%s",string[i]);` will fail on the first and all following entries because the prior scanf( "%d") left a newline in the input stream and the scanf("%s") will not read past the newline

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You declare your `mergesort()` as follows:

```
void mergesort(int l,int r,char **string,char *order)
```

But then you invoke it as follows:

```
mergesort(0,T-1,string,order);
```

Where `string` is defined as follows:

```
char string[X][Y];
```

So, this is wrong: your mergesort expects a pointer to an array of pointers to char, and you are passing it an array of char.

<sub>And if your compiler is not giving you an error, or at least a warning for this, then this means that you are trying to develop software without the bare minimum warnings enabled, or you are using your compiler in some compatibility mode for some *paleolithic* version of C.  Which is a lost cause.  So, before fixing anything, before even touching your code again, figure out how to ***enable all warnings*** on your compiler, or how to get your compiler to compile for the latest C standard.</sub>

To fix this, you could either do what @kkk suggested, which tough might be a bit of work, because you'd have to fix the way your mergesort function works, or you could try to declare your `string` variable as follows: `char** string;`  Then, you would have to allocate memory for it, with something like this: `string = malloc( T * sizeof char* );` and then, right before reading each string, allocate each string like this: `string[i] = malloc( (MAX + 1) * sizeof char );`  I don't have a C compiler handy, so I can't verify that I got the syntax exactly right, but this should help you get started.

Comment: "you are passing it an array of char."  No, he is passing an array of arrays of char.  Or, once automatic conversions are taken into account, he is technically passing a pointer to an array of char.  Either way, that's not the same thing as an array of char.

Comment: @JohnBollinger you might very well be right, but please bear with me for a moment: since it is not actually possible to pass an array of something to a function in C, clearly, when speaking of passing an array of something, we always actually mean passing a pointer to that array, no?

Comment: so what should i do? @Mike

Comment: @MithilLeua What is the input which you type, and what is the expected output ?

Comment: input:dcfbae
5
face
ace
cafe
deaf
fade                                                                                                          output:                                                                                                           deaf
deaf
fade
fade
ace

Comment: Mithil, I amended my answer.

Comment: No, ***not wrong answer.***  I already said, "I don't have a C compiler handy, so I can't verify that I got the syntax exactly right, but this should help you get started."  Stack overflow is not about fixing your warnings;  It is not even about writing your code for you;  Stack overflow is about helping you ***learn*** how to get your code running.

Comment: @MikeNakis i know that..was just telling..one doubt char [][MAX] is call by reference or by value..??

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are asking.  Arrays are always passed by reference in C.  But what I am suggesting is that you should use `char**` instead of `char[][]`.

Comment: @MikeNakis, the type of `string` in function `main()` is array of `T` arrays of `MAX` chars.  In that sense, when `string` is given as an argument to function `mergesort()` the argument is an array of arrays.  Yes, in this context, as in most others, that is converted to a *pointer* to the first element of the array, and the pointer is what is actually passed.  But the first element of an array of arrays of char is an array of char.  So as I said, after automatic conversions, the argument is a pointer to an array of `MAX` chars.  That type can be spelled `char (*)[MAX]`.

Comment: @MithilLeua, C has *only* call-by-value.  However, if you pass a valid pointer (by value) then you can use it to modify the pointed-to object.

Comment: @MithilLeua, That is what happens when a function argument has array type -- instead of the array itself being passed, a pointer to its first element is passed.  You can use that pointer to modify the first element, and from it you can compute other pointers with which you can modify the other elements.  C syntax provides for that to be largely transparent, but you do need to get the declarations right.

Answer (score 2):

If the purpose is to avoid a crash or segfault avoid warnings first.
by the way char ** and char [][] are not different.

change this

```
void merge(int l,int r,int mid,char **string,char *order){
```

to

```
void merge(int l,int r,int mid,char string[][MAX],char *order){
```

and this

```
void mergesort(int l,int r,char **string,char *order){
```

to

```
void mergesort(int l,int r,char string[][MAX],char *order){
```

Now you'll run into not working state

Comment: `char * order` must be `char order[MAX]` I think.

Comment: "char ** and char [][] are different" -- well, yeah. `char[][]` is not a valid type at all.

Comment: @Missu, no.  `char *order` is fine when the corresponding argument is declared as `char order[MAX]`.  Of course, the form you recommend is *also* ok.

Comment: @MithilLeua How do you exactly use the program ? you type 3 letters (abc) then you type What, 3 ? and then what next ?

Comment: i'll enter the orderstring then no of strings that i want to sort(say n) and then next n strings..

Comment: and one more doubt char[][MAX] is call by value or by reference?

Answer (score 0):

Well I do not Understand your code but at least I can give you a code with no errors and you can check where is the problem in your code.

If you get wrong Answer it happens because you coded wrong.

Here is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<string.h>

#define MAX 1001

int min(int x,int y){
    return (x>y)?y:x;
}

int check(char a,char b,char *order){
    int i,x=0,y=0;

    for(i=0;i<(int)strlen(order);i++){
        if(a==order[i])
            x=i;
        if(b==order[i])
            y=i;
    }

    if(x>y){
        return 1;
    }else{
        return 0;
    }
}
int compare(char *a,char *b,char *order){
   int i=0,l1=(int)strlen(a),l2=(int)strlen(b);

   for(i=0;i<min(l1,l2);i++){
       if(a[i]==b[i]){
            continue;
       }else{
           if(check(a[i],b[i],order)==1){
            return 1;
           }
       }
   }

   return 0;
}

void merge(int l,int r,int mid,char string[][MAX],char *order){
    int size1=mid-l+1;
    int size2=r-mid;
    char a[size1][MAX],b[size2][MAX];
    int i,j,k;

    for(i=0;i<size1;i++){
        strcpy(a[i],string[l+i]);
    }

    for(i=0;i<size2;i++){
        strcpy(b[i],string[mid+1+i]);
    }

    i=0;
    j=0;
    k=0;

    printf("before :\n");

    for(i=0;i<size1+size2;i++)
       printf("%s\n",string[i]);
    while(i<size1 && j<size2){
       if(compare(a[i],b[j],order)==0){
          strcpy(string[k],a[i]);
          i++;
       }else{
            strcpy(string[k],b[j]);
            j++;
        }
        k++;
    }

    while(i<size1){
        strcpy(string[k],a[i]);
        i++;
        k++;
    }
    while(j<size2){
        strcpy(string[k],b[j]);
        j++;
        k++;
    }
}

 void mergesort(int l,int r,char string[][MAX],char *order){
    int mid=(l+r)/2;

    if(l<r){
        mergesort(l,mid,string,order);
        mergesort(mid+1,r,string,order);
        merge(l,r,mid,string,order);
    }
}

int main(void){
    char order[MAX];
    int t,i;

    if(scanf("%s",order) != 1){
        exit(1);
    }

    if(scanf("%d",&t) != 1){
        exit(1);
    }

    char string[t][MAX];

    for(i=0;i<t;i++)
        if(scanf("%s",string[i]) != 1){
        exit(1);
    }

    mergesort(0,t-1,string,order);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> ```
> michi@michi-laptop:~$ ./program
> acb
> 2
> cab
> bac
> before :
> cab
> bac
> ```

Comment: what is the difference you created here? sorry i didn't get that..all inputs starts with a newline..So i think no need to write scanf("")!=- 1..

Comment: yep...sorry but comment out the before part..printf statement and the following for loop..